# Learning Selenium and unable to invoke the chrome browser using Selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm able to invoke the browser using this line which I know is incorrect because I added .exe to the key
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver.exe","C:\WebDriver.exe");
but somehow it works.

However the correct one `

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDriver.exe");
```

keeps giving me a No such Driver Exception. I've set the path in System variables as well and tried everything else. When I run the driver it runs fine.

How is the incorrect code working and correct one not working. Please help.

I've imported the selenium jars from maven repository and added them as dependency in POM file. tried setting the path in system variables to get it to resolve but still nothing. My chrome version is Version 115.0.5790.171  and the driver is also for version 115. Here's the error Im getting

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: chromedriver located at C:\WebDriver.exe, but invalid
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:45)

```
type here
```

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:13)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
at introduction.selintroduction.main(selintroduction.java:12)
```